# How to remove and add items in uipickerview in swift 4.?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift4, uipickerview

I have three text fields for which I am showing the same pickerview as drop down for choosing the values. So the condition is that I have 5 values in an array with values red, blue, green, yellow, black. 
So the condition is

1. These three text fields cannot have same value. That is if for first textfield 1 if I choose red as value from picker the value " red " should be removed or disabled from picker view when I select textfield 2 or text field 3 .
2. And if I change the value of textfield 1 from red to black from picker view the value red which is disabled or removed should get added back to the pickerview when I click on textfield 2 or textfield 3.

The code which I am trying is:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFiled1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFiled2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFiled3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    var Array = ["Blue", "Green", "Red", "White", "Grey"]
    var indexOfPicker = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func minusButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if Array.count != 0 {
            Array.remove(at: indexOfPicker)
            pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func plusButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if textFiled.text != "" {
            Array.append(textFiled.text!)
            pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return Array.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return Array[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        indexOfPicker = row
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for editing. Can you please help me in this regard!?

Comment: You have only one textfield in your code?

Comment: No Rajesh I have 3 textfields . This is just the starting code which I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFiled1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFiled2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFiled3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    var selectedTextField:UITextField?

    var colorsArray = ["Blue", "Green", "Red", "White", "Grey"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textFiled1.delegate = self
        textFiled2.delegate = self
        textFiled3.delegate = self

        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        let tempArr = colorsArray.filter { ![textFiled1.text!,textFiled2.text!,textFiled3.text!].contains($0) }
        return tempArr.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        let tempArr = colorsArray.filter { ![textFiled1.text!,textFiled2.text!,textFiled3.text!].contains($0) }
        return tempArr[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let tempArr = colorsArray.filter { ![textFiled1.text!,textFiled2.text!,textFiled3.text!].contains($0) }
        self.selectedTextField?.text = tempArr[row]
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    }
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.selectedTextField = textField
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents() 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rajesh. Can you please explain didBeginEditing logic. Will it be called when I present uipickerview on taping UITextField

Comment: When you tap in any textfield this delegate method will be called and reference of that textfield will be stored in a variable called selectedTextField. When you select some value in picker view the selected text will be assigned in appropriate textfield. In pickerview datasource methods I've used filter to remove if any textfiled contains the color remove it from pickerview datasource array. Check updated answer

Comment: Rajesh if you post a sample GitHub project by any means will be a great help for me :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rajesh... I will surely check and get back to you if I need some assistance..

Comment: Sure rajesh I updated with green tick but upvoting I did but since my reputation is less than 15 it may not show publicly

Comment: array out of bounds it is throwing

Comment: @ElizabethMoly Can you upload ur project in github?

Comment: Throwing array out of bounds in title for row when again scrolling the picker view after already setting the same uitextfield with uipicker view.

Comment: Rajesh same project that you uploaded in github

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189531/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-elizabeth-moly).